# Add a delay before shooting bullet (UPBGE)

Tags: game-engine, properties, logic-bricks

When I mouse click the bullet fires automatically. Is there a way for the bullet to fire a second (or any set time) after the mouse click? I feel like other questions have addressed how to add delays between bullets but not before initial independent shots. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are numerous ways to implement delays, in this case for firearm firing. I will focus on the two easier methods: <kbd>Logic Tics</kbd> & <kbd>Property Integers</kbd>. The property type can be float too if you'd prefer.

**Blender Math:** 60 tics = 60 frames = 1 second

## Example: Logic Tic

[image]

## Example: Property (integer)

[image]

## Download: Blend File

Unfortunately PasteAll.org is not accepting my blend file, either because it's a Blender +2.8x file or perhaps because it doesn't recognize new UPBGE source, so I've uploaded my blend to one of my Github repositories for commeridistribution.
https://github.com/RandomPandaStudios/BSE-Firing-Delay-Examples

## Download: Revision

https://github.com/RandomPandaStudios/BSE-Firing-Delay-Examples/blob/main/UPBGE_03_Firing_Delay_Example_v2.blend

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the file you sent is a default blend file when opened?

Comment: At the time of the upload, I was using the very latest UPBGE 0.3x release. Perhaps you need to update your UPBGE version? Additionally if you have a original Blender application set as your default program to open a blend file, you're going to need to either manually open my blend in your UPBGE 0.3 program or set your UPBGE 0.3 program as the default program for blend files.

Comment: Ok yes it works when opened on the newer UPBGE. I was actually asking about having a slight delay after clicking left mouse button, i.e. the bullet appears a split second after the button is clicked, but this is useful anyways so thanks.

Comment: You can easily implement this by using a boolean to keep track of whether the button has been clicked or not. Use this in combination with either of integer setups that I demonstrated in the blend file. I can create another blend example it if you want. But maybe best to create another question thread for that.

Comment: Could you create another blend file please? I think this may be useful for other people too. Thanks.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/RandomPandaStudios/BSE-Firing-Delay-Examples/blob/main/UPBGE_03_Firing_Delay_Example_v2.blend